# How to get images from gallery and display them to the screen in android sdk

Tags: android, image, sdk, get

I would like to know how to get a pre-saved image from the gallery and then display it onto the screen. Any tutorials/helpful links and info would be appreciated. If there is anything you would like me to explain more, please ask.

Answer (score 5):

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
```

This Intent used to pick the images from your SD cards and use `onActivityResult()` for get image and display the image in `ImageView.`

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
switch (requestCode) {
case 1:
 {
  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
  {
    Uri photoUri = data.getData();
    if (photoUri != null)
    {
    try {
          String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
          Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(photoUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null); 
     cursor.moveToFirst();
 int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
 String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
 cursor.close();
 Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
 image.setImageBitmap(bMap);

 }catch(Exception e)
  {}
  }
}
}
}
```

now we get chossed  image from gallery and then set image to ImageVIew.Here `image.setImageBitmap(bMap);` set the image to ImageView.

Comment: you should always check if cursor.MoveToFirst actually can be executed or you will get an exception if no media returned:

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {main code}